# Difference between 結ぶ and つなぐ

Tags: word-choice

In the context of tying things, e.g. shoe laces, rope, neck tie etc, I think 結ぶ is the correct verb. In all these cases can I replace 結ぶ with つなぐ? Would it change the nuance?

I have a feeling that つなぐ is more general than 結ぶ. My feeling is that 結ぶ can only be used for the sort of things I listed above, but つなぐ can also be used for other things like bridges connecting islands、connecting people etc. Is my feeling correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

繋ぐ is "to join" or "to connect", whereas 結ぶ is "to tie", "to knot", etc. They are usually not interchangeable. 靴紐を繋ぐ and ネクタイを繋ぐ sound very weird because nothing is joined. ロープを繋ぐ and ロープを結ぶ may be interchangeable when you are trying to extend a rope by tying it to another rope. 手をつなぐ and 手を結ぶ are also interchangeable, but the latter (yes, the latter) tends to have a figurative meaning ("to become partner with ～", "to collaborate").